# Porting Joomla extensions to Drupal / Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla

I have a few Joomla modules that I want to port to Drupal / Wordpress.

How much of difference is there between Joomla modules and extensions for Drupal / Wordpress ?

Secondly, is there a standard I can follow so that I don't need to explicitly develop for one of these CMSes and be able to make just one extension that installs on all three ? Would make the maintenance work a lot easier.

Comment: If you can list the modules you need, maybe I can help you with a list of similar plugins for wordpress.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is there is no such standard I'm afraid.

Joomla extensions follow the MVC pattern and are very much OO based, Drupal uses a complex hook system based on function naming standards, and last I checked Wordpress module code is totally procedural (it's been a while since I looked at WP though so this has probably/hopefully changed).

The three just aren't compatible.